# "That of" usage

Tags: relative-pronouns

I want to know if we can use "that of" as a relative pronoun in following situations.

> 1) The percentage of male smokers always outnumbers that of females.
>
> 2) Although the proportion of male smokers experiences a downward
>   trend, that of females witness an upward trend.

Comment: They are not relative clauses, so "that" is not a relative word, but a demonstrative. It is anaphoric, though, to the NPs "the percentage" / "the proportion".

Comment: In the second sentence, the verb _witness_ should be singular, like _experiences_.